# Other language Sorting(like hindi, not english) for Excel sheet column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, language, sorting

How can I sort excel sheet column for other languages like hindi(not english)?

Comment: did u find any solution for your question..?

Answer (score 1):

Sorting depends on regional settings of your system. If you want another sorting, that can be solved by VBA script.

Comment: Please can you give VBA script link?

Answer (score 0):

Even more precisely, if you're on Windows. Sorting depends on **Format:**

**Start ► Control Panel ► Region and Language:**

[image]

Too bad there are no options if I want sorting to be on English alphabet while Date formats on local settings...